# Failed audit but can't review deleted answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7953500) in Low Quality Posts, but I can't review the answer to see what I missed because it has been deleted.

The post included a link to a third-party tool, as well as sample code that could be used to solve the problem.  Didn't seem spammy to me, but I'd like to know what I missed.

Would a 10K user be so kind as to post a screenshot so that I can see what I missed?

Comment: I would imagine the user started spamming the same links to his product to as many questions as possible, as he has clearly since been entirely deleted as a spam account.  You should be very wary of posts advocating the use of a product from a review queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that if you see a link in a Low Quality Review queue, always check that user's other questions and answers to see if there's a pattern of posting the same link.

Some spammers are getting very savvy, and embedding their link in what looks to be an answer.  Clicking the user's profile in this case, however, would have shown they have no answers, a very strong indication of how to proceed next.

I can't tell you how many times I've clicked a user's profile, and either seen 0 answers, or 6 answers all spamming the same link.

---

Here's the screenshot you asked for:

[image]

Comment: Bonus fun with Google and caching:  Searching for the first sentence on Google gets me [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2MVMT9BLKH8J:stackoverflow.com/tags/office-interop/hot%3Ffilter%3Dyear+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).  Looks like "Stan" managed to rack up 200 reputation and a few badges before getting nuked.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I think I was (subconsciously) equating an audit with a "test," and felt that looking to see if the answer or user was still available would be "cheating."

Comment: Audits are mostly to see if you're paying attention; if you take the time to "cheat" and look at a user's profile, you're doing more than most reviewers do, and I think that's a Good Thing.  Also, the spam ring has apparently popped back up again already:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=msword2image.com.  I've flagged 'em all for moderator attention ;)